# When I add custom post type permalink rewrite, my regular post permalinks stop working. Can't get both to work at the same time

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

really struggling with this one, so any help would be much appreciated. My site has both regular post posts, and a custom post type called "articles."

I'm trying to get it to work so that my regular posts will use the /%category%/postname%/ permalink structure, (which I have set up in settings). This is working fine, until I add a custom rewrite for my article post type. I'd like articles to follow a /%issue%/%postname%/ structure.  I can get this working great with the following:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_show_permalinks', 1, 2 );

function wpa_show_permalinks( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'article' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'issue_tax' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%issue%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

where my post type is registered like this:

```
function article_post_type() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Magazine Articles', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Magazine Article', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Magazine Articles', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'      => __( 'Magazine Articles', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Article:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Articles', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'            => __( 'New Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Article', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => '%issue%',
    'with_front'          => false,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true,
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'article', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Magazine Articles and Features', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'issue_tax', 'category', 'featured_media', 'tag' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'article', $args );

}


add_action( 'init', 'article_post_type', 0 );
```

I add that, reset permalink settings, and the article permalinks start working as indended -  BUT  - as soon as I get that working, my regular posts start displaying a 404.

Why am I unable to get both to work at the same time? Am I missing a piece somewhere?

Thanks for any advice!

-erin

---

Just a follow up to my question - perhaps the thing that I'm really struggling with is why is the post_type_filter function affecting more than just the article post type that I have specified?

Thanks, 
Erin

---

Ok, one more super strange thing. This all works if I pass a query parameter at the end of my custom post links, so this works: http://www.mysitename.com/spring-2015/test-article-here/?post_type=article but this gives me a 404 http://www.mysitename.com/spring-2015/test-article-here/

Why would that be? I'm sorry for so many questions, just really trying to get to the bottom of this..!

Thanks again, 
Erin

Comment: It sounds like it could be a conflict in your slugs - check to make sure that whatever you're trying to name your custom post type slugs aren't conflicting with your other non cpt slugs.

Comment: Check this document as well and make sure you are staying clear of anything that could break your slugs/taxonomy https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: hi buschschwick - thanks for the reply -  I've double checked slugs and can't see anything that would conflict.  But I think I've isolated the exact thing that causes the regular posts to break - it's when I add the 'slug'                => '%issue%' line to my register post type function.  Why would a line in this function have anything to do with my regular post posts?

Comment: Have you tried setting the slug different for testing purposes? Such as: `'slug' => 'testslug'` and see if you get the same result

Comment: If I use a static slug, it all works, but I"m trying to use a custom taxonomy term there.  Weirdly though, if I try switching out the %issue% variable for %issuedate% - the custom post type permalink is the thing that breaks, and the post permalink is fine.  I don't have %issue% defined anywhere else - but why else would that make a difference? grr this is frustrating..!

Comment: More weirdness - I can get both posts and my custom permalink to work, but only if I ditch the %category% from my post permalinks, and only if I use %issue% for my custom post type permalink. BUT - then PAGES are broken...!!

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too sure to be honest, apologies. I don't work that way much. Not sure if it will help, but heres a custom post type and taxonomy that I made today and works great maybe by just looking at it might cause a lightbulb to go off. Good luck!

Comment: Sent the function via chat...

Answer (score 0):

Replace   `'slug' => '%issue%',` with `'slug' => 'article/%issue%',`

It will definitely work, I have tested it. Kindly note that "article" is the post type name.

Also Save permalinks after making above change.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer above:
Replace: `Replace 'slug' => '%issue%',` with `'slug' => 'article/%issue%',`
That didn't work fully for me, so I had to change my post_type_link filter as well.
All I had to do was to change following:

```
return str_replace( '%issue%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
```

With:

```
return str_replace( 'article/%issue%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
```

It's a bit strange and I spent several hours figuring this out. Hope it helps someone in the future!